# The type "geography" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT WorkId, 
RegisterDate , Location

FROM (

SELECT dbo.[Work].WorkId ,
dbo.[Work].RegisterDate , dbo.Look.Location

FROM dbo.Municipality INNER JOIN
dbo.[Work] ON dbo.Municipality .Municipality Id = dbo.[Work].MunicipalityWorkId INNER JOIN
dbo.Look ON dbo.[Work].LookWorkId = dbo.Look.LookId
WHERE (dbo.Look.Location IS NOT NULL) AND Type= 1

) E

GROUP BY WorkId ,RegisterDate , Location
```

And I get this error :

> The type "geography" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP
>   BY clause.

I need to add Location to Group By, because I need to display Location in the database. What is the solution for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Post the complete query.

Comment: convert/cast to something else then group? it kinda makes sense to me not be able to group by geography...

Comment: Please post the custom user type for `geography`?  You may be missing a flag in your definintion - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187630(v=sql.105).aspx .  According to that site `You can perform ORDER BY, GROUP BY, and PARTITION BY operations with user-defined types if the type supports binary ordering. A type is binary ordered if it has the IsByteOrdered flag set to true in the SqlUserDefinedType attribute that is specified as part of the type definition. This flag indicates that the binary representation for the type is in the semantically correct order for that type.`

Comment: Unless you have horribly misnamed columns, you shouldn't need to use `GROUP BY`. You're grouping by `WorkId`. That name indicates it's unique in the `Work` table. You're joining on the `MunicipalityId` and `LookId` columns of the `Municipality` and `Look` tables. Those names indicate they're unique in their tables. What duplicates were you getting that made you think to do any grouping at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

Convert the `Location` to text using `Stastext` and use it `Group by`. Then convert it back to geo in `Select` using `STGeomFromText`

```
SELECT WorkId,
       RegisterDate,
       geography::STGeomFromText(Location.STAsText(), 4326)
FROM   (SELECT dbo.[Work].WorkId,
               dbo.[Work].RegisterDate,
               dbo.Look.Location
        FROM   dbo.Municipality
               INNER JOIN dbo.[Work]
                       ON dbo.Municipality.MunicipalityId = dbo.[Work].MunicipalityWorkId
               INNER JOIN dbo.Look
                       ON dbo.[Work].LookWorkId = dbo.Look.LookId
        WHERE  ( dbo.Look.Location IS NOT NULL )
               AND Type = 1) E
GROUP  BY WorkId,
          RegisterDate,
          Location.STAsText()
```

Referred from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121403/sql-geography-data-type-column-in-group-by-clause)

**Note :** The geography function are **CASE sensitive** it should be used as it is

- STGeomFromText
- STAsText

Comment: In last line, Should it be `STGeomFromText`? Thanks.

Comment: No no it should be `Stastext` it is used to convert Geography data to `nvarchar` so that it can be used in `Group by`

Comment: So where should I use `STGeomFromText` ?

Comment: @jason - It should be used in `SELECT`. I have already used that in my query `geography::STGeomFromText(Location.Stastext(), 4326)`

Comment: I get this : `Could not find method 'Statstext' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'`

Comment: @jason - It is because of `Stastext` it should be `STAsText`. Updated check now

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: the problem with this approach is that equal geography can represented differently in WKT

Answer (score 0):

You an not using  aggregate function like sum or count so you could avoid group by  and order by

```
SELECT 
    WorkId
  , RegisterDate 
  , Location

FROM (
    SELECT 
          dbo.[Work].WorkId 
        , dbo.[Work].RegisterDate 
        , dbo.Look.Location
    FROM dbo.Municipality 
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Work] ON dbo.Municipality.Municipality Id = dbo.[Work].MunicipalityWorkId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Look ON dbo.[Work].LookWorkId = dbo.Look.LookId
WHERE (dbo.Look.Location IS NOT NULL) AND Type= 1
ORDER  BY WorkId ,RegisterDate , Location
) E
```

Comment: Isn't there another solution? Because my actual query is based on Group By

Comment: I changed my query to what you said and I got this : `The geography data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`