# How can I find out if lightning struck the same place twice?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, geography

I am learning how to use SQL and I want to work out if lightning has struck the same location more than once in 2019 using a dataset from NOAA.

[This is the first couple of rows of the data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odR8t.png)

I have tried multiple strategies for counting unique locations from the centre_point_geom column for example:

`COUNT(DISTINCT center_point_geom)`

but I keep getting this error message:

> Aggregate functions with DISTINCT cannot be used with arguments of type GEOGRAPHY

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type "geography" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043713/the-type-geography-is-not-comparable-it-cannot-be-used-in-the-group-by-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use geography type in aggregate function - you should transform it into string like in below example

```
count(distinct to_json_string(center_point_geom))
```

Meantime, if you are looking for count of lighting struck same deo_point - you should just use count without distinct - `count(center_point_geom)`

and full select statement could look like below

```
select any_value(center_point_geom) center_point_geom
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by to_json_string(center_point_geom)
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! In case you were interested, 3883 locations experienced more than one lightning strike in the US in 2019.